# Phonegap Accelerometer only calls Error Callback

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

this is my code:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("Device Ready");
    startWatch();

};

function startWatch() {

    // Update acceleration every 5 seconds
    var options = { frequency: 5000 };
    watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);
};



function onSuccess(acceleration){

    console.log('Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + 
       'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + 
       'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + 
       'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp);
};

function onError(){
    console.log("Acceleration Error occured");
};
```

I test it on 2 Android Phones (Samsung Galaxy Nexus GT-I9250, Android 4.0 and Huawei Ideos X3, Android 2.3.3), from my console outputs I know both only call the Error Callback, but why?

I can't find the cause for this on google, so please help if you have an Idea.

Comment: So I just tried your script on my Nexus One with Android 2.3.6 and PhoneGap 1.2 and it worked fine. Perhaps you should post your AndroidManifest.xml and any other pertinent source code.

Comment: I would like to bump this question, please, as I am encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a timing issue.

You should try the following which runs successfully on my HTC Evo or post your whole app:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PhoneGap</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("Device Ready");
    startWatch();

};

function startWatch() {

    // Update acceleration every 5 seconds
    var options = { frequency: 5000 };
    watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, accelerometerError, options);
};



function onSuccess(acceleration){

    alert('Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + 
       'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + 
       'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + 
       'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp);
};

function accelerometerError(){
    alert("Acceleration Error occured");
};

function init() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
}
</script>

  </head>
  <body onload="init();" id="stage" class="theme">

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any useful messages in logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you are passing in a reference that does not exist to your watchAccelerometer() call?

You are passing in onError, but the name of your handler is accelerometerError

Comment: that is my bad, I copied the wrong code. The names are correct in my source code, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thought.  I have not tested this (my Mobile Dev machine is at home), but it occurs to me that you may need to tell Android devices that you want to use the accelerometer in your Android Manifest.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
```

Do you have that setting in your manifest XML file?

Comment: NOTE: I tried this, and on my Nexus One it worked with or without this setting.